# What is '@_silgen_name' in Swift language?

Tags: swift, darwin

While reading Darwin library in Swift 2.2, I found below codes.

```
@warn_unused_result
@_silgen_name("_swift_Darwin_sem_open2")
internal func _swift_Darwin_sem_open2(
  name: UnsafePointer<CChar>,
  _ oflag: CInt
) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<sem_t>
```

What is '@_silgen_name' in the 2nd line?

I found a below information from [here](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-dev/Week-of-Mon-20151207/000265.html), but I want more detail information, like the Apple Developer Library.

> If it’s just a specific set of Swift functions you want to call from C, you can use the @_silgen_name attribute to override the mangled name, and/or make them @convention(c) to use the C calling convention.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`@_silgen_name` was just recently renamed from `@asmname` ([see the following commit](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/fbd2e4d872d1aa57bfba2ab1f4d280bb1e90cbb8)) with the following commit message:

> This reflects the fact that the attribute's **only for
>   compiler-internal use**, and isn't really equivalent to C's asm
>   attribute, since it doesn't change the calling convention to be
>   C-compatible.

So as a general Swift developer, one wouldn't come across this attribute, unless working with, say, porting Swift to some other platform.

Now, `@_silgen_name` is an attribute (macro) for the class `SILGenNameAttr` with certain options, where the latter is part of Swifts [abstract syntax tree (AST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). From the [`swift/AST/Attr.def` source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/include/swift/AST/Attr.def) (see also [swift/lib/AST/Attr.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/lib/AST/Attr.cpp))

```
// Schema for DECL_ATTR:
//
// - Attribute name.
// - Class name without the 'Attr' suffix (ignored for
// - Options for the attribute, including:
//    * the declarations the attribute can appear on
//    * whether duplicates are allowed
//    * whether the attribute is considered a decl modifier or not (no '@')
// - Unique attribute identifier used for serialization.  This
//   can never be changed.
//
// SIMPLE_DECL_ATTR is the same, but the class becomes
// SimpleDeclAttr<DAK_##NAME>.
//

DECL_ATTR(_silgen_name, SILGenName,
          OnFunc | OnConstructor | OnDestructor | LongAttribute |
          UserInaccessible, 0)
```

We find the declaration of `SILGeneNameAttr` in [swift/AST/Attr.h](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/include/swift/AST/Attr.h):

```
/// Defines the @_silgen_name attribute.
class SILGenNameAttr : public DeclAttribute {
public:
  SILGenNameAttr(StringRef Name, SourceLoc AtLoc, SourceRange Range, bool Implicit)
    : DeclAttribute(DAK_SILGenName, AtLoc, Range, Implicit),
      Name(Name) {}

  SILGenNameAttr(StringRef Name, bool Implicit)
    : SILGenNameAttr(Name, SourceLoc(), SourceRange(), /*Implicit=*/true) {}

  /// The symbol name.
  const StringRef Name;

  static bool classof(const DeclAttribute *DA) {
    return DA->getKind() == DAK_SILGenName;
  }
};
```

To sum up; it's related to provide a Swift interface for C functions. You will most likely have a hard time finding any details regarding `SILGenNameAttr` in the developer library, and can consider it an undocumented feature.

---

Finally, the following talk with Russ Bishop might be of interest to you:

- [Unsafe Swift: For Fun & Profit](https://realm.io/news/russ-bishop-unsafe-swift/).

> **The Toolbox: Here there be dragons (34:20)**
>
> I would not ship this in a production application under any
>   circumstances. But if you’re feeling adventurous, here they are.
>
> `@asmname` is an attribute to decorate a function. You definitely need
>   to understand the ABI to use this one. Swift will not help you
>   marshall the parameters very much. The compiler is not going to be
>   very forgiving, so you have to make sure that you’ve manipulated your
>   parameters into a format it’s compatible with. The following code
>   shows how to declare it. Give the function attribute, `@asmname`, and
>   the string symbol; then function its arguments in return type. The
>   compiler will not complain if you get the arguments wrong or return
>   type incorrectly. It only expects that that symbol exists, and when it
>   jumps to it, it better take those arguments and have that return type.
>
> ```
> @asmname("dispatch_get_current_queue") func _get_current_queue() -> dispatch_queue_t
> ```
>
> **Q&A (37:08)**
>
> **Q**: *Obviously not all of these are documented by Apple, so what’s your process of discovering all these behaviors?*
>
> **Russ**: I’ll look at the documentation first, but you’re right that there is a lot of stuff that isn’t in there. If you go to the Swift
>   REPL and use the flag — I think it’s something like
>   `-deprecated-integrated-repl` — you can ask it to print the Swift module and all the bits that Xcode doesn’t show you. If you dig into the
>   toolchain directory Xcode, you can also find stuff in libswiftCore and
>   libswiftRuntime.
>
> **JP**: If you’re interested in doing some more unsafe things with Swift, you can do a code search in GitHub for `@asmname` and language
>   “Swift”, and you’ll see a bunch of really bad but interesting stuff.

A slightly older post from Bishops' blog:

- [Swift - Don't do this](http://www.russbishop.net/swift-don-t-do-this).

> ...
>
> First off notice the `@asmname` attribute. This is the equivalent of
>   `DllImport` or `extern`. It tells Swift that we are going to link in
>   some library that defines a function with the given name and matching
>   the given arguments. *"Just trust me Swift, I know what I'm doing"*.
>   Hint: You had better know what you're doing.

Comment: Great answer!  Does Apple reject iOS apps that use this attribute?

Answer (score 2):

To say short,
`@_silgen_name` defines a name of the function shown on shared library.

[Glibc.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/adef0368bb233f1a838c67d732298f86a8b4cd3d/stdlib/public/Glibc/Glibc.swift#L41) tells that _swift_Glibc_open is defined.

you can see this by `nm /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftGlibc.so` like this.

```
00000000000016f0 t _swift_Glibc_fcntl
0000000000001700 t _swift_Glibc_fcntlPtr
00000000000016b0 t _swift_Glibc_open
00000000000016c0 t _swift_Glibc_openat
00000000000016d0 t _swift_Glibc_sem_open2
00000000000016e0 t _swift_Glibc_sem_open4
```