# How to use @asmname() in Swift 3.0

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7.3, swift3

I have the code perfect running in Xcode 7.2.1, Swift 2.1, and I just upgraded the new Xcode 7.3, Swift 3.0.

How can I use `@asmname()` with Swift 3.0.

[image: xcode]

Comment: `@asmname` was removed from Swift 3.0. You can use `@_silgen_name` as its replacement. The rename was done to really drive home the fact that you should not be using either `@asmname` or `@_silgen_name`.

Comment: Thank you for your helping. I found that from google and you.

Comment: Related: [What is '@_silgen_name' in Swift language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030998/what-is-silgen-name-in-swift-language/)

Answer (score 2):

As of Swift 2.2 `@asmname` has been renamed to `@_silgen_name`.

Related test change in [this commit](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/88d558c7c2cab889f650520cfb014595094250b6), name change in [this file](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/attr/attr_silgen_name.swift), and the [changelog](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).