# Can I use @_silgen_name to expose an [Objective-]C or C++ symbol that is not a function to Swift?

Tags: swift

Consider a private `CFLocaleKey` that is later bridged as an `NSLocaleKey` (`NSString`) for use internally with `NSLocale`:

```
CF_EXPORT const CFLocaleKey kCFLocaleTemperatureUnit API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.12), ios(10.0), watchos(3.0), tvos(10.0));
```

[CFLocale_Private.h](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/CoreFoundation/Locale.subproj/CFLocale_Private.h)

The most obvious way to reference something like this would be through a bridging header.  But is there a way to reference this `CF`/`NSLocaleKey` with pure Swift using something like `@_silgen_name`?

First I tried:

```
@_silgen_name("NSLocaleTemperatureUnit")
public let temperatureUnit: NSLocale.Key
```

But the compiler complains:

> @_silgen_name cannot be applied to this declaration

Ok, let's make it static, but static properties can only be declared on a type.  So I tried setting it up in the way the other `NSLocaleKey` values are bridged to Swift, as an extension on `NSLocale.Key`:

```
extension NSLocale.Key {
    @_silgen_name("NSLocaleTemperatureUnit")
    public static let temperatureUnit: NSLocale.Key
}
```

Even with this, the compiler complains with the same error as above.  This is where I got stuck.  Does `@_silgen_name` only work for functions?  Is what I'm asking even possible with pure Swift?

Comment: I believe `@_silgen_name` is only an attribute to decorate functions, I have never seen it used for a type.

Comment: @dfri I've only seen it on functions as well, I've been looking through the Swift open source repo.  Any alternatives (or ideas) for "externing" a type in pure Swift?

Comment: Based on the quotes from Russ Bishop [in this related answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35035099/4573247), I don't believe `@_silgen_name` can help you out in this case. As for alternatives or ideas, at the top of my name: no, not really, sorry :/

Comment: This might not be applicable in your case, but looking at [the comments in SR-5246 JIRA ticket](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5246), possible [the following approach from `NSSwiftRuntime.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSSwiftRuntime.swift#L83) (using the `@_cdecl` attribute and casts of types to `UnsafeRawPointer`) could possible shed at least some insight on your problem.

Comment: We're definitely getting closer, but `@_cdecl` may only be used on 'func' declarations.  Thanks for a step in the right direction!

Comment: @dfri looks like we have our answer: https://twitter.com/JALsnipe/status/894200528003051521

Comment: Good to get an answer directly from someone from the Swift compiler dev. team, even if it maybe wasn't the one your were looking for. Interesting Q&A nonetheless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of writing (August 8th, 2017), this currently is not possible with any version of Swift (3 or 4).

Without a header declaration, clang isn't sure how to map something in Swift back to C.  `@_silgen_name` and `@_cdecl` work on functions, but not for variables.

This was confirmed by Jordan Rose, a Swift compiler engineer at Apple on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/JALsnipe/status/894200528003051521).

tl;dr:

> [anything but func is hard.](https://twitter.com/UINT_MIN/status/894613028708143105)